# How can I record only part of a live source with gstreamer?

Tags: sockets, gstreamer

Application consists of two pipelines:

Sending pipeline

```
filesrc ! decodebin ! encoder ! payloader ! udpsink
```

Receiving pipeline

```
udpsrc ! rtpbin ! depayloader ! decoder ! encoder ! filesink
```

The wanted behavior is that the sending pipeline plays a file, and when that has finished, another file plays and recording starts.

The actual behavior varies. With some approaches it is that the recording starts from the same time that the first playback starts. This I believe is due to that the pipelines share the same GSocket, in order to get it to work at all. So somehow data coming to the socket must be buffered.
Other approaches result in a few frames from before the recording should start, and then jumps to after the recording begins, resulting in a messy picture (i-frames without keyframe).

I've tried a couple of different approaches to try to get the recording to start at the right time:

- Start the receiving pipeline when the second file starts playing
- Start both pipelines at the same time and have a valve element dropping everything until the second file starts playing
- Start both pipelines at the same time and Seek to the time where the second file starts playing
- Start both pipelines at the same time and have the receiving pipeline connected to a fakesink until and switch to the real filter chain when second file starts playing
- Set an offset on the receiving pipeline

I would be very grateful for any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Start both pipelines at the same time and have a valve element dropping everything until the second file starts playing*

This actually works. The problem I had was that no picture fast update was sent, and it took a while for the next keyframe to arrive by itself.